# Javascript Syntax Error only in IE 6 and IE 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm getting the error below in IE6 and IE7 only

```
Line 1
Char: 6
Error: Syntax error
Code: 0
URL: https://websitename.com/sublevel/page.aspx?param=123456&param2=Parameter Name&param3=4
```

in view source line 1 is empty

Any idea why is it happening only in IE6 and IE7

Here is my javascriptcode

```
function OpenChatForm(id, paramname, param3) {
  $("#ChatForm").dialog("open");
  $("#Iframe0").attr("src", "page.aspx?param=" + id+ "&param2=" + paramname+ "&param3=" + paramr3);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Please post the javascript.  But my guess is somewhere in there you have an extra comma in an object literal.

Comment: Could you serve some JS-Code :-)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: There must be more javascript.  Please also post the code that calls this function.

Comment: Can you try `var url = "page.aspx?param="+encodeURIComponent(id)+ "&param2="+encodeURIComponent(paramname)+"&param3="+encodeURIComponent(param3); $("#Iframe0").attr("src",url);`

Comment: AND by the way - the error is likely in the resulting page and not in your script

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but it's the same error

Answer (score 0):

Get your code to pass the [jslint](http://jslint.com) and I'll bet you that the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this was a typo when you entered it, the variable `param3` is misspelled as `paramr3` when used in your function.  Should be:

```
function OpenChatForm(id, paramname, param3) {
  $("#ChatForm").dialog("open");
  $("#Iframe0").attr("src", "page.aspx?param=" + id+ "&param2=" + paramname+ "&param3=" + param3);
     return false;
}
```

Comment: it was a typo when I entered it